# Is there any way to watch Amazon Video on Samsung Gear VR?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s7, samsung-gear-vr, amazon-video

Netflix and Hulu have both apps for the Samsung Gear VR headset, but Amazon Video doesn't have an app.  So my question is, is there any way to watch Amazon Video on Samsung Gear VR?

I tried going to the Amazon Video website on the Samsung Internet VR web browser, but when I click an episode it just tells me to download the "Amazon Underground" app, which is a non-VR app for watching Amazon Video on the Samsung Galaxy S7.  Also, I tried clicking "request computer version" in the Samsung VR browser, to trick the site into thinking that I'm on a computer, but then Amazon just displays a message that your browser is not supported.

Is there any way to change the user agent of the Samsung VR browser to something which makes Amazon play the video?

Answer (score 0):

There was some speculation around March 2016 about some job offers posted by Amazon, that some commentators interpreted as a hint that they were preparing a VR app for their video service. See [this article](http://variety.com/2016/digital/news/amazon-video-vr-app-1201725533/) for example.

However, more than one year later no official statement by Amazon has been issued, and no app has appeared.

It seems that the only alternative currently is to use the unofficial application [SideloadVR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sideloadvr.market), as suggested for example by [this post answer](https://forums.oculus.com/community/discussion/48130/amazon-prime-on-gear-vr).

However, it seems than currently not all the Gear VR devices are supported, as suggested by the reviews (and developer replies) on the Play Store. In particular support for popular Galaxy S8/S8+ devices is yet to come.